# Remove All Whitespace Before and After Tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to remove **all** the whitespace before and after all table objects in my word document.

This is the code I have so far:

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^p^p"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

This seems to delete some new line breaks but not all of them. After I have run this macro, when I click to Show all hidden characters it still shows some of the |P tags.

Answer (score 2):

Try change

```
.Text = "^p^p"
```

to

```
.Text = Chr(32)
```

To find out which characters to replace, select your text and run the following macro.

```
Sub DebugAscCode()
For i = 1 To Len(Selection.Text)
    Debug.Print Asc(Mid(Selection.Text, i))
Next i
End Sub
```

Using replace on VBA

```
Sub ReplaceAscCode()
Dim tmpArray As Variant

tmpArray = Array(7, 13, 32)

For j = LBound(tmpArray) To UBound(tmpArray)
    Selection.Text = Replace(Selection.Text, ASC(tmpArray(j)), "")
Next j

End Sub
```

I've used in my work and it works perfectly this way, each character will always be represented by an ASC code

[]'s

Comment: It doesn't really look like this does anything, thanks though.

Comment: chr (32) is the code for the space characters that you want to remove, have you tried?

Comment: Yeah I tried it, both in the .Text and .Replacement.Text and it didn't quite do what I was after. I'm trying to remove all newline characters outside of the table, not sure what this actually does.

Comment: Ah this was helpful, but still not quite perfect. It returns a lot of Chr(7) "CR" and Chr(13) "BEL" so I replaced them but still no luck.